# How to make a reference to "lstlisting"?

Tags: listings

I have this format to my codes, and i want to make a refference, i used \ref{} but dont work. How can I solve that?

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption = code, label=lst:E269]

\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: You should use `\ref`, not `\refe`.

Comment: sorry add an extra "e" by mistake. Yes i use \ref, but dont work

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @MaxRom: [This code](https://pastebin.com/raw/Kd7mux7v) produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKUFX.png). If you don't get the same, then post a minimal example that replicates your current behaviour.